# how to calculate a key inside an array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I want to calculate a key inside an Array in C#, but i dont know how

here is my json

```
{ "id": "1312312312", "customer_name": "Tatang Sutarman", "table_number": "12", "Cart": [ { "product_name": "Mineral Water", "amount": 3, "price": 1000, "subtotal": 3000 }, { "product_name": "Coca Cola", "amount": 5, "price": 2000, "subtotal": 10000 } ], "total_price": 0 }
```

here is my object classes

```
public class OrderRRModel 
{
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
    public string customer_name { get; set; }
    public string table_number { get; set; }

    public IList<ListCart> Cart { get; set; }

    public OrderRRModel()
    {
        Cart = new List<ListCart>();
    }

    public double total_price { get; set; }
}

public class ListCart 
{
    public string product_name { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double subtotal { get; set; }

    public double GetTotal()
    {
        var subtotal = amount * price;
        return subtotal;
    }

}
```

i want to calculate the subtotal inside the array and the results I will put in total_price

can you tell me how to do it ???

Comment: `total_price = Cart.Sum(x => x.subtotal)` ?

Comment: I wonder why you have both `amount` and `price` as well as `subtotal` in your data. This is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this in your model

```
public double total_price 
{ 
    set 
    {
        total_price = Cart.Sum(x => x.GetTotal());
    } 
    get;     
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `get {return Cart.Sum(x => x.GetTotal());} `, or?

Comment: thanks i got the total_price, but how do i get the subtotal ??? it still 0

Comment: same way you can set {subtotal = amount * price;} in CartList model and use Cart.Sum(x => x.subtotal); in OrderRRModel  model

Comment: what about the get ?
        public double subtotal { get; set { subtotal = amount * price; } }

it shows error "get must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern"

Comment: *no you have to set* - did you try it? I bet it will crash with a stack overflow exception.

Comment: can you help me mr @KlausGütter 
`public double subtotal { get; set { subtotal = amount * price; } }`

what should i input in that get ??

Comment: `public double subtotal { get { return amount * price; } }`